# Decorate Write-Operation for MPI-usage

Tags: fortran, mpi, decorator

Given Code with many write-statements, I want to parallelise this code with MPI. To prevent every but the first process from printing I wrote a Subroutine to decorate the write-statements and replaced every write with a `CALL masterPrint(...)`.

```
SUBROUTINE masterPrint(msg,nr)
  USE datatypesMod
  IMPLICIT NONE    
  CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN)              :: msg 
  INTEGER,OPTIONAL, INTENT(IN)              :: nr
  !---------------------------------
  IF(myRank .EQ. 0) THEN
    IF(PRESENT(nr)) THEN
      WRITE(*,*)  msg,nr
    ELSE
      WRITE(*,*) msg 
    END IF
  END IF
END SUBROUTINE masterPrint
```

datatypesMod defines myRank. I put an optional parameter into this subroutine, because the original-code has many debug-prints like `WRITE(*,*) "value of x:", x`. But then I saw that there are more and different combinations (e.g. with arrays). I thought of concatenating everything into one string, but the type conversion is very tedious for so many write-statements.

Is there any good solution to prevent multiple writes from every process without the need to put every write into an if-statement?

Edit: possible solution from the comments: [standard output in Fortran MPI code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649218/standard-output-in-fortran-mpi-code)

Comment: This question probably has quite a lot of overlap with http://stackoverflow.com/q/5649218 There that question actually proposes a potential solution: Use an explicit unit in the write statements, this unit is associated with stdout (or a logfile) on rank 0 and with /dev/null on other ranks.

Comment: I think your links should solve my problem and I dismiss my idea of decorating the write-statement.

Comment: I don't think decoration is that bad. I am using it without any real problems. `if (Iam_master) write...`